# Update DataTable records by Id in C#

Tags: c#

Could anyone please suggest, I have a datatable with 100 records and want to update any 1 specific record based on id.

Comment: And the usual comment follows: What have you tried?

Comment: Let's first show us what you tried and where it doesn't work...

Comment: Dear members of StackOverflow. I have a problem. Could you help? (It is like you post sounds here)

Comment: Dear user of StackOverflow. Everyone here has problems, that's the reasons we're all here: to help each other. BUT to avoid questions that merely say "I have to do this. Do it for me" it's **REQUIRED** (please read FAQ or meta...) you show your **EFFORT** (in form of code you wrote or things you tried/thought). Often people that don't do it are called _help vampires_ and many many questions are closed for this reason. Help doesn't replace your own thinking. First tool of each developer isn't SO but his brain. (I'm not a native speaker so sorry if this sounds _too_ rude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, maybe it helps even if your reqirement is not that clear:

```
DataRow row = tableWith100Rows.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<int>("ID") == 4711); 
if(row != null)
    row.SetField("ColumnToUpdate", "new value");
```